# How to ensure that duplicates of an instance remain linked

Tags: python

(I'm not entirely sure what to title this so please correct it)

I'm trying creating a very rudimentary game engine in Python and have come across a major issue. In this engine, there are classes such as `Space`, `Vector` and `Line`. `Vector` contains all the stuff a vector might need, `Line` represents lines and can render them and `Space` is a class that manages rendering and collision detection.

In `main.py`:

```py
space = Space()
line = Line(Vector(0, 0), Vector(10, 10))  # line.start and line.end

space.add_obj(line)

while True:
    line.rotate(1)  # rotate 1 degree

    space.step()  # render all objs
```

This is a basic example of how I would like `line` to rotate and then be displayed through `space.step()`. The issue is that in both `Vector` and `Line` a lot of methods return a new instance, and so if I do `line.rotate(1)` the `line` that has been passed into `space.add_obj` doesn't rotate at all and so the displayed `Line` won't rotate at all.

`vector.py`:

```py
def __add__(self, other: float | int | Vector) -> Vector:
    if type(other) not in [float, int, Vector]:
        raise TypeError(
            "'other' must be of type 'float', 'int', or 'Vector', not"
            + f" {type(other)}"
        )

    if type(other) != Vector:
        result = Vector(*[a + other for a in self])
    else:
        result = Vector(*[a + b for a, b in zip(self, other)])

    return result
```

`line.py`:

```py
def rotate(self, angle: float | int, point: Vector = None) -> Line:
    if type(angle) not in [float, int]:
        raise TypeError("'angle' must be of type 'float' or 'int'")

    if point != None:
        if type(point) != Vector:
            raise TypeError("'point' must be of type 'Vector'")
    else:
        point = self.middle()

    return Line(
        self.start.rotate(angle, point),
        self.end.rotate(angle, point),
        self.colour,
        self.width,
    )
```

I have tried to make some of these methods like `Vector.__add__` to change the current instance instead of returning a new modified instance but it raises a lot more issues with modifying values when you don't want it to.

I would like for the `Line` that gets passed into `Space.add_obj` to remain a simple copy of the one in `main.py` so that if I modify one instance they both change, the only issue is that the moment one of the methods are called the instance is changed and they are no longer copies

Comment: You *don't* want a copy; `add_obj` should likely just be storing a reference to the line you pass. If you want to update a vector in-place, define `Vector.__iadd__` as well, then use `x += y` instead of `x = x + y` to perform the update.

Comment: How do I make it so that it stores a reference to the line? Also, I kind of see what you're saying with `__iadd__` and I did have it implemented for a while but then removed it out of thought that it was redundant but I don't quite see your point with this

Comment: You don't have to do anything. That's what `space.add_obj(line)` does. You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Okay, but what if I want `space` and `main.py` to refer to the same `Line`? Currently they don't because like I said a lot of methods in `Line` and `Vector` return a new instance and so if I do `line.rotate()` in `main.py` it will no longer be the same `Line` that `space` will refer to

Comment: So don't return a new instance from `line.rotate`. Just update the values of `self.start` et al. If you want the option of rotating in place and creating a new rotated line, you should use two different methods (similar to how `list.sort` and `sorted` are both defined).

Comment: Okay, but now let's say (since I've tried this as well) I create a very basic circle object and pass it to `space` then in `main.py` I add 5 to the circles `x` coord. It doesn't update the coords that have been passed to `space` because all of the dunder methods return new instances and have to else it causes more issues. This case will only work if I make the dunder methods self-mutating which isn't good. Is this where the `__iadd__` comes in handy?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what the `__i*__` methods are for. `__add__` should return a new object without modifying either operand; `__iadd__` should update `self` in place (and return `self`, since `x += y` is implemented as `x = x.__iadd__(y)`, not just `x.__iadd__(y)`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249196/discussion-between-thermohalia-and-chepner).